# How is the probability of winning a block calculated from the difficulty?

Tags: difficulty, mining-profitability, hashpower

I have problem finding this. The Bitcoin wiki mentions the probability [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target#What_is_the_target_now.3F), but only with a link to the [current value on BlockExplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/q/probability).

The wiki page on [difficulty](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) doesn't mention the formula for the probability either.

Comment: What probability are you after? The probability of a hash solving a block (as per Peter's explanation), or a share solving a block? Or the number of blocks you might solve or shares you might submit in a given time period?

Comment: The probability of a hash solving a block. I don't know how the share system works, isn't that implemented differently for each different pool specification?

Comment: Yes, variable difficulty shares means that strictly speaking "shares per block" is meaningless. In this context though most would take "shares per block" to mean "Difficulty 1 shares per block", which have a probability of exactly 1/Difficulty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the current difficulty is D, then the target hash (the value below which block hashes must go) is:

> 0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 / D

(by definition of difficulty, which is a fraction of the maximum target), or otherwise put, the number of valid hashes is:

> 65535 * 2<sup>208</sup> / D

Which means that the ratio of all hashes over valid hashes would be:

> 2<sup>256</sup> / (65535 * 2<sup>208</sup> / D) =
>   D * 2<sup>48</sup> / 65535 =
>   D * 4295032833

Which, at the current (January 2017) difficulty of D =  392963262344.3704 means that one hash in

> 392963262344.3704 * 4295032833 = 1687790113931869416948

results in a valid block, or each attempt has a chance of

> 1 / 1687790113931869416948 = 0.000000000000000000059 %

Comment: I think the third equation is the formula for all possible hashes, not "the fraction of valid hashes to all possible hashes", isn't it? Shouldn't there be a "1/" in front?